# OSMDroid5 : can't get zoomToBoundingBox() working correctly

Tags: osmdroid

I have problem to use ``zoomToBoundingBox()```.
According to what I've read somewhere here, I've created my own MapView class to call zoomToBoundingBox() in On Layout(). Here is my code:

public class MyMapView extends MapView {

```
    public void setBoundingBox(BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox) {
        this.boundingBox = boundingBox;
    }

    private BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox = null;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        super.onLayout(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);

        // Now that we have laid out the map view,
        // zoom to any bounding box
        if (this.boundingBox != null) {
            this.zoomToBoundingBox(this.boundingBox);
        }
    }
}
```

So, In my fragment I initialize the boundingBox:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    final BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox = new BoundingBoxE6( ... );
    // this gives ``N:44899816; E:5020385; S:44899001; W:5019482``

    mMapView.setBoundingBox(boundingBox);

    mMapView.invalidate();

}
```

So, the calculated bounding box should obviously cause to get a max zoom level but it doesn't.

First, problem in calculation; `onLayout()` is called after `onResume()` and I explored the code of `zoomToBoundingBox()` and here are the results on each data calculated:

```
zoomLevel = 0
maxZoomLatitudeSpan = 55.08
requiredLatitudeZoom = 14.0  // I have a big doubt on this result!
maxZoomLongitudeSpan = 472.07
requiredLongitudeZoom = 17.0  // hum well, better but not best expected value
```

So `zoomToBoundingBox()` will choose a zoom level of 14.0 why?
Anyway, requiredLongitudeZoom of 17.0 is not the best result.
As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhtwH.jpg), the max level of 18.0 is possible.

So how should I use `zoomToBoundingBox()` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that `this.mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox);` resulted in a sub-optimal zoomlevels for some situations so i Implemented my own version.

Adapted from [LocationMapFragment.java](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/locationmap/LocationMapFragment.java)

```
private void zoomToBoundingBox(BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox) {
    GeoPoint min = new GeoPoint(boundingBox.getLatSouthE6(), boundingBox.getLonWestE6());

    GeoPoint max = new GeoPoint(boundingBox.getLatNorthE6(), boundingBox.getLonEastE6());
    ZoomUtil.zoomTo(this.mMapView, min, max);
    // this.mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox); this is to inexact
}
```

Adapted from [ZoomUtil.java](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/osmdroid/ZoomUtil.java)

```
public class ZoomUtil {
    public static void zoomTo(MapView mapView, IGeoPoint min, IGeoPoint max) {
        MapTileProviderBase tileProvider = mapView.getTileProvider();
        IMapController controller = mapView.getController();
        IGeoPoint center = new GeoPoint((max.getLatitudeE6() + min.getLatitudeE6()) / 2, (max.getLongitudeE6() + min.getLongitudeE6()) / 2);

        // diagonale in pixels
        double pixels = Math.sqrt((mapView.getWidth() * mapView.getWidth()) + (mapView.getHeight() * mapView.getHeight()));
        final double requiredMinimalGroundResolutionInMetersPerPixel = ((double) new GeoPoint(min.getLatitudeE6(), min.getLongitudeE6()).distanceTo(max)) / pixels;
        int zoom = calculateZoom(center.getLatitude(), requiredMinimalGroundResolutionInMetersPerPixel, tileProvider.getMaximumZoomLevel(), tileProvider.getMinimumZoomLevel());
        controller.setZoom(zoom);
        controller.setCenter(center);
    }

    private static int calculateZoom(double latitude, double requiredMinimalGroundResolutionInMetersPerPixel, int maximumZoomLevel, int minimumZoomLevel) {
        for (int zoom = maximumZoomLevel; zoom >= minimumZoomLevel; zoom--) {
            if (TileSystem.GroundResolution(latitude, zoom) > requiredMinimalGroundResolutionInMetersPerPixel)
                return zoom;
        }

        return NO_ZOOM;
    }
}
```

Note that the code only works if the mapview is initialized completely else the calculation of the ground resolution fails or produces wrong results