# OSMDroid: Can't figure out how to correctly use zoomToBoundingBox()

Tags: osmdroid

As explained [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/236) and for which I'm still waiting for an answer, I cannot figure out how to use zoomToBoundingBox() when I launch my map's fragment.

Basically, I guess I should call it in onResume() but obviously doing so is not taking in account.

I wonder if osmdroid is not missing an onMapReady() callback as we have in GoogleMaps API...

Comment: is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577385/osmdroid5-cant-get-zoomtoboundingbox-working-correctly/35607435#35607435 from the same author?

Comment: @k3b, yes but I realized that the bad `zoomToBoundingBox()` calculation came from the moment where I call it and obviously, calling from `onResume()` causes a problem. Maybe using `OnFirstLayerListener()` can help but I didn't have time to test it.